# By update new version of iOS App,the older version of iOS App of AppId is not working

Tags: react-native-ios

I update new version of iOS App.when I update the older version to new version, older version AppId is not working.

I am using older version  of iOS AppId for update new version it will show the error is "App not found" in my console.

I am using   react-native with iOS.

Comment: Have some code?

Comment: getAppstoreAppMetadata("AppId") 
           .then(appVersion => {

      console.log("Welcome Appstore2");

             let appStoreReleaseVersion = appVersion.version;
             let appCurrentVersion = DeviceInfo.getVersion();
    console.log(appStoreReleaseVersion);
    console.log(appCurrentVersion);
             if(appCurrentVersion !== appStoreReleaseVersion) {
               this.renderUpdateAlert();
             }
           })
           .catch(err => {
      console.log("In this appId app is not found");
             console.log(err);
           });
  }
 }

Comment: above code I am using Replace to AppId to MyAppId.but One AppId is Working fine.another AppId is not working.

Comment: I am using same code in both AppIds.but one AppId is working fine.another AppId is not working it shows the error is "App not found" .